# Determining the End-of-stream

Tags: rust

I made a loop for a webserver.
On a windows client I didn't have any problems but on a linux client the server didn't responding to requests.

The problem: I found out that if `request_size % buffer_size == 0` then the loop runs once more waiting for more data.

The question: Is there an efficient way of reading data that takes into consideration slow connections, connections that drop packages. (Not just using non_blocking or nodelay.)

```rust
let listener = TcpListener::bind("127.0.0.1:80").unwrap();

while let Ok((mut stream, _)) = listener.accept() {
  let mut data: Vec<u8> = Vec::new();
  let mut buf = [0u8; 32];
  while let Ok(size) = stream.read(&mut buf) {
    data.extend(buf[..size].iter());
    if size != buf.len() { break; }
  }

  // do something with the data
}
```

I could increase the buffer size but that wouldn't solve the problem.

Comment: A stream, and a TCP connection is a stream, can always delay unpredictably. You might want to check the completeness by other means, for example by evaluating a header. -- And the expected size can also match the buffer size.

Answer (score 6):

First, to detect EOF reliably, you should test the returned `size` of `Read::read` against zero and not your buffer size, because if you have a 'slow connections' you might not get enough data to fill the entire buffer at once, causing your loop to quite early with an incomplete message in `data`.

---

There are essentially 3 ways to make *sure* you received the entire message:

- Read until EOF
- Read a fixed-sized message
- Encode some 'content length' and read that many bytes

Notice, that only the last two variants allow your client to eventually send more data over the same stream. Also notice, that these two variants can be implemented comparably easy via `Read::read_exact`.

*Besides notice, if you don't trust your client, it might be helpful to set up `TcpStream::set_read_timeout` with a reasonably long timeout (e.g. 2 min).*

### Read until EOF

This is probably the easiest and, according to your title and code, probably the method you are aiming for. However, to generate an EOF, the client must shutdown at least its write channel. So, if your server is stuck in `read`, I assume you forgot to shutdown your client (tho I have to guess here).

On the server side, if you really want to read until EOF, you don't need a loop yourself, you can simply use the `Read::read_to_end` utility function. Here is an example for a client & server with the client sending a *single* message terminated by EOF:

```rust
use std::io::Read;
use std::io::Write;
use std::net::TcpListener;
use std::net::TcpStream;

// --- Client code
const SERVER_ADDR: &str = "localhost:1234";
pub fn client() {
    let mut socket = TcpStream::connect(SERVER_ADDR).expect("Failed to connect");
    // Send a 'single' message, the flushes kinda simulates a very slow connection
    for _ in 0..3 {
        socket.write(b"Hello").expect("Failed to send");
        socket.flush().unwrap();
    }
    // Instead of shutdow, you can also drop(socket), but than you can't read.
    socket.shutdown(std::net::Shutdown::Write).unwrap();
    // go reading, or whatever
}

// --- Server code
const SERVER_BIND: &str = "127.0.0.1:1234";
pub fn server() {
    let listener = TcpListener::bind(SERVER_BIND).expect("Failed to bind");
    while let Ok((stream, _)) = listener.accept() {
        let _ = handle_client(stream); // don't care if the client screwed up
    }
}
pub fn handle_client(mut socket: TcpStream) -> std::io::Result<()> {
    let mut data: Vec<u8> = Vec::new();
    // Read all bytes until EOF
    socket.read_to_end(&mut data)?;
    println!("Data: {:?}", data); // or whatever
    Ok(())
}
```